# gas-tank should be a tag synonym of fuel-tank

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

gas-tank should be a  tag synonym of fuel-tank

This question is an example of one with both tags:

[How to know how much fuel is left when the light turns on](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-to-know-how-much-fuel-is-left-when-the-light-turns-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done

[gas-tank](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas-tank) now converts to [fuel-tank](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel-tank)